# delete the data after reading the file in c or (save the remaining data in another file)

Tags: c, file

I have a file, which contains elements data. In that file, first line first have the information of line numbers.

for example,
 first word is 10;   i have to read and print next ten lines in the first output file and remaining in second output file. the example file format is given below.

i have tried to write code. but, result is wrong. my code is attached for your kind perusal.

**Input file**

```
10 1631  
1 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000
2 0.00000000000000e+000 7.50000000000000e+001 0.00000000000000e+000
3 7.49999999999987e+001 7.50000000000000e+001 0.00000000000000e+000
4 7.49999999999987e+001 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000
5 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000 7.49999999999987e+001
6 0.00000000000000e+000 7.50000000000000e+001 7.49999999999987e+001
7 7.49999999999987e+001 7.50000000000000e+001 7.49999999999987e+001
8 7.49999999999987e+001 0.00000000000000e+000 7.49999999999987e+001
9 1.49999999999997e+002 7.50000000000000e+001 0.00000000000000e+000
10 1.49999999999997e+002 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000
11 1.49999999999997e+002 7.50000000000000e+001 7.49999999999987e+001
12 1.49999999999997e+002 0.00000000000000e+000 7.49999999999987e+001
13 2.24999999999996e+002 7.50000000000000e+001 0.00000000000000e+000
14 2.24999999999996e+002 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000
15 2.24999999999996e+002 7.50000000000000e+001 7.49999999999987e+001
16 2.24999999999996e+002 0.00000000000000e+000 7.49999999999987e+001
17 2.99999999999995e+002 7.50000000000000e+001 0.00000000000000e+000
18 2.99999999999995e+002 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000
```

**First output file**

```
1 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000
2 0.00000000000000e+000 7.50000000000000e+001 0.00000000000000e+000
3 7.49999999999987e+001 7.50000000000000e+001 0.00000000000000e+000
4 7.49999999999987e+001 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000
5 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000 7.49999999999987e+001
6 0.00000000000000e+000 7.50000000000000e+001 7.49999999999987e+001
7 7.49999999999987e+001 7.50000000000000e+001 7.49999999999987e+001
8 7.49999999999987e+001 0.00000000000000e+000 7.49999999999987e+001
9 1.49999999999997e+002 7.50000000000000e+001 0.00000000000000e+000
10 1.49999999999997e+002 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000
```

**Second output file**

```
11 1.49999999999997e+002 7.50000000000000e+001 7.49999999999987e+001
12 1.49999999999997e+002 0.00000000000000e+000 7.49999999999987e+001
13 2.24999999999996e+002 7.50000000000000e+001 0.00000000000000e+000
14 2.24999999999996e+002 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000
15 2.24999999999996e+002 7.50000000000000e+001 7.49999999999987e+001
16 2.24999999999996e+002 0.00000000000000e+000 7.49999999999987e+001
17 2.99999999999995e+002 7.50000000000000e+001 0.00000000000000e+000
18 2.99999999999995e+002 0.00000000000000e+000 0.00000000000000e+000
```

**My code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Cord;
FILE * file_out;
FILE * file_input;
FILE * Elements_out;

int Co_Ordinates(FILE *file_input);

int main() {
    char line[256];
    int result;

    file_input = fopen ("simple_CSDexample.dat", "r");
    file_out = fopen ("File_output.domm", "w");
    Elements_out = fopen ("second part.domm", "w");

    result = Co_Ordinates( file_input ) ;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_input)) {
        printf("%s", line);
        fprintf(Elements_out, " %s", line);
    }

    fclose(file_input);
    fclose(Elements_out);
    fclose(file_out);

    return 0;
}

int Co_Ordinates(FILE *fp) {
    char line[256];
    int lineno;
    int NO_Cord;

    fscanf(fp, "%d ", & NO_Cord);
    lineno = 0;

    if (lineno >= 1 && lineno <= NO_Cord) {
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
            if(lineno == NO_Cord - 1) {
                return 0;
            }

            lineno++;
            printf("%s \n" , line);
            fprintf(file_out, "%s", line);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'lineno = 0;'...'if (lineno >= 1' - never true.  Use your debugger!

Comment: What number is `1631`? I think that it is necessary to skip if it is not necessary.

Comment: Indentation needs work in that  ' Co_Ordinates' function - the flow of control is hard to folow, and may lead to bugs.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY.. after reading the first element we have to skip the remaining data

Comment: Also, is 'Co_Ordinates' supposed to return something useful?  It only ever returns 0, but there is an 'if' statement that should control when it returns with.. 'something not 0'  ?

Comment: OK, I used a code block to clean up the indentation for you.  Now it is clear that the bulk of 'Co_Ordinates' will never execute.

Comment: @MartinJames can you please let me know, how to clear the error and execute it.

Comment: There are multiple probems, some of which @BLUEPIXY and I have highighted. Fix them first, and retest.  We don't know or sure your intended design, eg is 'Co_Ordinates' supposed to return the number of lines copied, or something?   Fix the issues already outlined and retest.  If there are still problems, edit/append the new info to the question, or build a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[256];

    FILE *file_input  = fopen("simple_CSDexample.dat", "r");
    FILE *file_output = fopen("File_output.domm", "w");
    int no = 0;

    if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_input) && sscanf(line, "%d", &no)==1){
        while(no-- && fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_input)) {
            fputs(line, file_output);
        }
        fclose(file_output);

        file_output = fopen("second part.domm", "w");
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_input)) {
            fputs(line, file_output);
        }
    }
    fclose(file_input);
    fclose(file_output);

    return 0;
}
```